# Exim: Error in system filter: malformed numerical string ""

Tags: debian, exim

When I send myself a mail with:

```
echo "test" | mail -n -s "test" user@example.com
```

I get the following error in `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`:

```
Error in system filter: malformed numerical string ""
```

How can I find the error in the system filter?

```
if $h_X-Spam_score_int is above 49
    and foranyaddress $recipients ($thisaddress contains "@example.at")
    then
        headers add "Old-Subject: $h_subject"
        headers remove "Subject"
        headers add "Subject: *** SPAM ($header_X-Spam_score points) *** $h_old-subject"
        headers remove "Old-Subject"
        #save /var/mail/suspect_spam
finish endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command gives you the name of the system filter file:

```
$ /usr/sbin/exim4 -bP system_filter
```

It's unset by default, so if it contains something, it must be set somewhere in your Exim configuration.

Comment: Thank you I have added the system filter to the question.

Comment: It very much looks like the message had no `X-Spam_score_int` header. What should have added it? Test this theory by replacing `$h_X-Spam_score_int` following the `if` with a literal `50`, sending mail again and checking the full headers of the arrived message.

Comment: You are right, I changed the condition to `if $h_X-Spam_score_int is not "" and $h_X-Spam_score_int is above 49` to fix the error.